# Запись в файл русских символов Python

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит текст с клавиатуры, программа отслеживает нажатые клавиши и записывает в файл с .txt . Проблема заключается в том, что записываются только символы английской раскладки, если вводить русские символы в файл записывается английский символ которому соответствует нажатая клавиша

**Вот фрагмент кода:**

```
import os
import keyboard

def pressedKey(key):
    with open("log.txt", "a") as openFile:
        openFile.write(key.name)
```

Comment: В данном примере текст не считывается, а уже хранится в переменной. И этот фрагмент работает, как и ожидается. Может проблема с получением текста с клавиатуры, а не с его записью в файл?

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, да, немного не так записала вопрос, исправлю. Проблема в в том, что клавиатуры считываются только буквы английской раскладки.

Comment: Это в корне меняет, и вопрос, и фрагмент кода. Отредактируй вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в том, что латиница входит в кодовую таблицу ASCII и все её символы умещаются в 1 байт. А вот с национальными алфавитами (в том числе - кирилицей) дело обстоит гораздо сложнее. Есть два варианта:

1. Пытаться впихнуть национальные символы в "верхнюю" часть **одно** байтовой таблицы ASCII, заняв чужое место. Так появились кодовые таблицы IBM866, cp1251 и КОИ8-Р. Достоинство в том, что один символ всегда помещается в один байт. Недостаток - в том, что "читатель" должен знать, в какой именно кодировке записан файл. Иначе увидите на экране "кракозябры". Кроме того, такой вариант не подходит для китайцев, японцев и т.д.
2. Второй вариант - использовать **много** байтовые кодировки - wchar или UTF8. Насколько мне известно, wchar придумали мелкософты и, на сегодняшний день, это их творение уже умерло. UTF8 имеет огромный плюс в том, что текст, набранный в этой кодировке будет читаться одинково везде, где поддерживается UTF8. На сегодняшний день весь линух перешёл на utf8. Виндузятники пока отстают, но движутся в этом направлении.
   Огромный минус UTF8 в том, что один символ может занимать несколько(!!!) байт. Поэтому понятия "длина строки" и "размер строки" становятся принципиально разными.

Теперь конкретно о вашей проблеме. Поддержка UTF8 на питоне реализована по разному в разные его версиях. В третьем питоне она полная и абсолютная. Во втором надо явно указывать, что вы работает с utf8 и кое где  надо явно преобразовывать кодировку.

В описании модуля *keyboard* (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) явно написано, что:

> full internationalization support

значит - дело не в кодировке, а в Вашем алгоритме. Так как Вы привели только часть программы, абсолютно непонятно, откуда берётся этот *key*. Подозреваю, что из вызова функции read_key или подобной.

Вот что написано в доке про эту функцию:

```
 read_key(suppress=False)
        Blocks until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event's name or,
        if missing, its scan code.
```

Понимаете, о чём речь? Эта функция возвращает вовсе **не** код символа, а имя события, соответствующего нажатию этой **клавиши**. Не символ, а клавиша! А если не может разобраться, то вообще - возвращает скан-код **клавиши**.

Попробуйте выполнить вот такую крохотную программку:

```
import os
import keyboard

def pressedKey(key):
    with open("log.txt", "a") as openFile:
        openFile.write(key.name)


def main():

    key_list = keyboard.record()
    for key in key_list:
        print(key, ' ' )
        pressedKey(key)

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                             
    main()
```

И вы увидите, что печатаются вовсе не символы, а названия событий. Событие нажатия на клавишу и событие отпускания клавиши. Пока Вы не нажмёте Esc. Этот модуль и предназначен именно для этого - для работы с **клавишами**, а не с кодами символов.

Comment: Ваши знания меня глубоко поражают! Однако внутри Python использует Unicode (UCS-2/UCS-4/Flexible String Representation) https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html, Windows же плотно сидит на UTF-16.

Comment: @0andriy Вообще-то, я в своём ответе **подчекнул**, что в этой библиотеке речь идёт не о **символах** (в любой мыслимой кодировке) а о **кодах клавиш*, которые ни к каким кодировкам не привязаны. И в доке даже написано, что если библиотека не может распознать клавишу, то она возвращает просто **скан-код**. Скажите, Вы мои сообщения хотя бы читаете, перед тем, как яростно критиковать? :-)

Comment: А вы читаете свои ответы? Пункт 2. у вас о кодировках с какими-то немыслимыми исследованиями кто и в каком направлении идёт. Потом рассуждения на тему, что используется в Python. А вы креативный!